# Can I insall multiple wordpress setups in AWS ElasticBeanstalk on single EC2 T1.micro instance?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to AWS and cloud computing in general. I want to create my own server where i can run the website of my clients using AWS ElasticBeanstalk and AWS EC2 instance. I have gone through the documents of AWS but it described single wordpress setup. I dont want to run WP Multisite, i want to make all the websites on standalone wordpress setup. The reason behind choosing AWS EB is it allows easy ssl setup for all the domain hosted on the server. I have no idea how to do it. any help would be appreciated. Please guide me and also correct me if i am wrong with my question

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably ***could*** (with enough configuration) get ElasticBeanstalk to support multiple WordPress setups, but EB is really designed for a single application per instance. Also, a `t1.micro` instance is pretty small, so you might not have enough computing resources to run multiple WP setups on the instance anyway.

If the only reason you're investigating ElasticBeanstalk is for easy SSL setup, then I think you're making things unnecessarily complicated. One of things that EB is setting up for you is an Elastic Load Balancer, which can be easily configured to support SSL no matter what kind of instances are behind the load balancer.

I'd suggest you look into using a regular EC2 instance (probably bigger than a `t1.micro`) and putting an ELB in front of it.

Comment: Thank you Brian, appreciate your help.